# Simple array loop question Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, arrays, loops

How can you make this work?

```
numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: ({int x = 0; while (x <= 60 ) { return x; x++; } })];
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Ha! You a Javascript/Ruby/Scheme/ML programmer by any chance?

Comment: Yep :)

Hehe, used to the other ways of doing things, Objective-C is unusual to me..
:P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray * array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i <= 60; ++i) {
  [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int myStrangeNumberOfItems = 61;

NSMutableArray * numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: myStrangeNumberOfItems];
for (int i = 0; i < myStrangeNumberOfItems; i++) {
    [numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
```

Comment: that is totally unacceptable.. it can make a spaceship go nuts

Comment: Fixed. ;) Never loop to <= if you don't need to.

Answer (score 2):

First, an NSArray can only hold objects, not primitives.  You can add the objects within a for loop like so.

```
NSMutableAray * numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int x = 0; x <= 60; x++)
    [numbers addObject:[NSNumber numberForInt:x]];
```